# Genus 2 surface equipped with hyperbolic metric is not a symmetric space.

Tags: differential-geometry

Because the genus 2 surface with hyperbolic metric has constant sectional curvature, its Riemann tensor is covariantly zero. i.e. $\bigtriangledown R \equiv 0$
Therefore, it is locally symmetric space. However, I can't understand why it is not a symmetric space. I guess this is because it has negative sectional curvature and it is compact, but I failed to prove it. Does every symmetric space whose sectional curvature is negative need to be non-compact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A compact surface of genus $g \geq 2$ (viewed as a complex curve uniformized by a constant-curvature metric) admits only finitely many automorphisms by [Hurwitz's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_automorphisms_theorem), hence admits only finitely many isometries (since every isometry is an automorphism or anti-automorphism of the holomorphic structure).

Comment: To be more specific, the local isometry that reverses geodesics at $p$ (which is a global isometry of the hyperbolic plane) does not give a globally-defined map of the surface.